# How to allow Visual studio to let me add files while it's debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, durandal

I'm writing a web app using Durandal and it's annoying to have to stop debugging and then restart everytime I add a new controller etc.

Comment: Maybe asp.net vnext with vs.net 2014 will support your requirements?!?

Comment: You are using managed code so of course you have to recompile every time you add additional managed code.  If you are just adding JS or HTML you don't have to stop debugging but when you are changing your managed code you will always have to.

Answer (score -1):

You could open 2 visual studio instances

1 for editing (don't debug with it, just edit / save / maintain your project)

A second one WITHOUT the project opened, and have it attached as a debugger to your IE/Firefox/Whatever you use for script debugging.

You can edit the 1st one all you want and the 2nd will only get it's source from live data when you refresh the page so it will be kept up to date. This allows you to change anything that runs in the client side, including adding files, without interupting your debugging session. Of course it doesn't help if you want to add server side compiled elements but there's no way to recompile without re starting debugging anyway.

Comment: It is strange but then again so is your scenario (it's uncommon to need to add files during a debugging session, modifying them, very common, add while running, rather uncommon, but add while debugging, i can't think of more than a couple times i'd have wanted to do that in years)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Basically want to either have IIS Express launched from outside of visual studio or move to full IIS locally.